# SkAction Run so fast

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
var actionArray = [SKAction]()
actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: obstacle.position.x, y: -obstacle.size.height), duration: TimeInterval(3.5)))
actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
obstacle.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

They are running so fast, and when I change the `timeInterval` they are just slowing down but distance decreases.

All I want is a slow down with a much larger distance!

Comment: You are not factoring distance over time,. You are saying move to a point in x seconds. So for example I am going from the left of the screen to the right of the screen in 3 seconds, and you are going from the middle of the screen to the right of the screen in 3 seconds.  I am going to run twice as fast as you because we both need to arrive at the same destination at the same time (3 seconds)

Comment: okay so what should be done you think ?? what distance over what time should be factorized ?

Comment: .... you factor in the distance over time, miles per second kilometers per second, points per second. It should take me twice as long to get to the end of the screen than you, so my duration should be 6 seconds, while yours is 3 seconds

Comment: sorry, you need to learn if you do not know how to do it in code.  I gave you the help, now research the rest

Comment: func getDuration(pointA:CGPoint,pointB:CGPoint,speed:CGFloat)->TimeInterval {
        let xDist = (pointB.x - pointA.x)
        let yDist = (pointB.y - pointA.y)
        let distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
        let duration : TimeInterval = TimeInterval(distance/speed)
        return duration

    }

Comment: check out the function that gets duration from disrtance per speed, what to change am really fed up with this thing

Comment: You do distance / (distance to travel per second), so your speed should be how many points you expect to travel in 1 second

Comment: Nope sorry, you already wrote the code. No need for me to write anymore.